# Python Conditions and If statements

Tags: python

```
age = input("how old are you?: ")
if age < 18:
    print (str("you are adoult!"))
elif age  > 1:
    print (str("you are chalid!"))
else:
    print ('you havant bored yet')
```

Не могу понять свою ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: age=int(input(...))

Comment: Thanks a lot) it was right

Comment: Рекомендую писать сообщения по-русски в коде. Или английский проверять тщательно:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых, вы в условии сравниваете строку с числом, так как `input()` возвращает строку. Поэтому нужно перевести строку в целое число. Это будет выглядеть так `age = int(input("how old are you?: "))`.

Во вторых, нет смысла переводит строку в строку как здесь: `print (str("you are adoult!"))`
Итоговый код с правками будет выглядеть так:

```
age = int(input("how old are you?: "))
if age <= 18:
    print("you are adoult!")
elif age  > 0:
    print("you are chalid!")
else:
    print("you havant bored yet")
```

Comment: Я вы программирование ещё новичок, так что спасибо что помогли найти мою ошибку)